# How best to implent 3-dimensional SQL relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**This question is an extension of [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643363/how-to-implement-many-to-many-to-many-database-relationship/49644209?noredirect=1#comment86314254_49644209) regarding many-to-many relationships in MySQL.**

I currently have 3 tables that I need to link with a 4th intermediary table:

`Stores`, `Products`, and `States`

My intermediary table, `_stores_products_states`, combines the `id` from the other three tables to determine which `product` is sold by which `store` and in which `state`.

Now, as I understand it, I would need to create an entry in `_stores_products_states` for every possible combination of the three, correct? This would lead to thousands of duplicated values in 1-2 of the columns (though never all 3).

For example, if **Best Guy** sells both **GI Bros** and **Darbies** in all 50 states, that would be 100 entries just for those two products. If those products are sold by another store, they too would have 100 entries.

Is this the correct way to implement this kind of relationship?

**EDIT:**
This whole setup is basically just to determine the availability of a particular product. A user will search for a product and receive a list of stores that sell that product in their state.

Comment: If the value for combination of `product_id, store_id, state_id` is required to determine which product in which store in which state has been sold, then you have no duplication. What does it matter if data for 2 columns would contain the same data? You need 3 pieces of info, you said it yourself - the 3 combined would never repeat. You're not far off, but you can sell the same product in the same store multiple times, right? What about that case? Do you simply increase quantity in that case?

Comment: This is just to determine availability of a particular product. Essentially, the user will search for a product and a list will show which stores sell that product in their state (think online store, not a local building).

Comment: That means that the table you're asking about is a sales ledger, but you're after product availability. So, if you are after product availability (product, store combo), why not create a table `product_availability` that connects `product` and `store` via foreign keys?

Comment: Because that doesn't take the state into account. The store can sell the same product in multiple states.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th table is the way!
So if I got it right, your '_stores_products_states' table could even be called sale

Comment: Not really. This is just to determine availability of a particular product, not record an actual sale.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a record for all *possible* combinations of product, state, and store. You only need to create a record for *existing* combinations, that is, availability of a product in a store in a state (maybe with things like local price and quantity bolted on).

You will have to store this information one way or another; a 3-relation link table, especially stored as a [clustered MySQL index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), would be a pretty standard solution, with good performance characteristics.

One thing I wonder about is why you have stores separate from states. I'd expect a store to be associated with a state. With the 3-relation link table, you'd be able to associate the same store with a product in several different states. Is this what your business domain supposes?

Comment: That is correct. In our real-world data, the store could sell the same product in multiple states, so it couldn't be linked to just one state.